# How to keep casing of properties in json returned by Asp.Net Core controller?

Tags: json, serialization, asp.net-core, json.net

We have some legacy js code that does ajax calls and expects the properties to be named Id, Name etc. By default the json serializer in Asp.Net Core camel cases the properties on the returned entity, but how can I tell it to use the same casing and in c# code?

Preferably I would like to set this per controller.

Comment: https://codeopinion.com/asp-net-core-mvc-json-output-camelcase-pascalcase/

Comment: The casing can be customized, but only on a global, application-wide basis. If you need one-offs, then all you've got is the `JsonProperty` attribute, which allows you to specify *exactly* what the name should be..

Comment: @ChrisPratt Can I create my own casing implementation?

Comment: Presumably. There's a `NamingStrategy` base class, and then derived classes from that such as `CamelCaseNamingStrategy`. Just do the samething: create a class that inherits from `NameStrategy` and then override the appropriate method(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For setting per controller, you could try `IResultFilter` or passing the `JsonSerializerSettings`.

For a Controller like below:

```
        public async Task<ActionResult> Test()
    {
        return Ok(new Product { Id = 1, Name = "test" });
    }
```

Options1

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> Test()
    {
       return new JsonResult(new Product { Id = 1, Name = "tt" },new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver() });
    }
```

Options2

1. Custom `IResultFilter`

   ```
   public class JsonSerializeFilter : IResultFilter
   {
   public void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext context)
   {

   }

   public void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext context)
   {
       var result = context.Result as ObjectResult;
       var value = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result.Value);
       context.Result = new ObjectResult(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
               result.Value,
               new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver() }
           ));
   }
   }
   ```
2. Use `JsonSerializeFilter`

   ```
   [TypeFilter(typeof(JsonSerializeFilter))]
   public async Task<ActionResult> Test()
   {
       return Ok(new Product { Id = 1, Name = "tt" });            
   }
   ```

Answer (score 3):

ASP.NET Core uses Newtonsoft for the serialization, so it should be as simple as adding the

`JsonProperty` attribute to all properties.

e.g.

```
public class ViewModel
{
     [JsonProperty("Id")]
     public string Id { get; set; }
     [JsonProperty("Name")]
     public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

You can also set various options in your Startup.cs class by adding the .AddJsonOptions() in the

```
ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
```

method.

Comment: I didn't specify that I was using anonymous classes here             return Ok(new
            {
                d = new
                {
                    Id = 123,
                    Title = "MyTitle",
                    LoginName = "MyLogin",
                    NameId = "MyNameID"
                }
            }); but maybe it's not possible to apply attributes to anonoymous types

Answer (score 2):

Our solution is an Angular app hosted on Sharepoint and it was using Sharepoint's web services, so just wanted to lift&shift it onto Asp.Net Core and see if it works.

I ended up doing this:

```
    JsonSerializerSettings _serializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
    {
        TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto
    };

    [Route("_api/Web/CurrentUser")]
    public IActionResult CurrentUser()
    {

        return Json(new
        {
            d = new
            {
                Id = 123,
                Title = "MyTitle",
                LoginName = "MyLoginName",
                NameId = "MyNameId"
            }
        }, _serializerSettings);
    }
```

This will return the properties as cased in the anonymous type.