# How to set WebApi to default to UpperCamelCase (Json)

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0

I would like to configure the default serializer of the WebApi so it should keep the name of the fields from the class.

```cs
namespace ChimuLambdaApi.Controllers;

[ApiController]
[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Route("[controller]")]
public class V1Controller : ControllerBase {
    private readonly ILogger<V1Controller> _logger;

    public V1Controller(ILogger<V1Controller> logger) => _logger = logger;

    [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.HttpGet("map")]
    public Beatmap GetBeatmap(long id) {
        return new Beatmap() { };
    }
}


namespace ChimuLambdaApi;

public class Beatmap {
    public int BeatmapId { get; set; }
    public double BPM { get; set; }
    public float AR { get; set; }
    public float OD { get; set; }
    public float CS { get; set; }
    public float HP { get; set; }
    public string File { get; set; }
}
```

This is what i got from WebApi results.

```json
   "beatmapId": 0,
   "bpm": 0,
   "ar": 0,
   "od": 0,
   "cs": 0,
   "hp": 0,
   "file": "string"
```

This is what i want to get.

```json
   "BeatmapId": 0,
   "BPM": 0,
   "AR": 0,
   "OD": 0,
   "CS": 0,
   "HP": 0,
   "File": "string"
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51983300/how-to-keep-casing-of-properties-in-json-returned-by-asp-net-core-controller/51984395 - see if this hels.

Comment: thx, but is it not possible to set a global settings in the WebApplication for Json serialization?
I want to keep the class as a return type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure the `JsonOptions` in your Program.cs.  Using the following configuration of `PropertyNameCaseInsensitive` and `PropertyNamingPolicy` you can achieve the functionality you want:

```
builder.Services.Configure<JsonOptions>(o =>
{
    o.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = false;
    o.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null;
});
```

This will configure the serializer to match the casing of your class properties. If you wanted different casing you could use `[JsonPropertyName]` attribute on the properties.

You could instead configure the same properties after `AddControllers` using `builder.Services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(...)`.

[image: example]

---

However, the majority of clients/serializers are configured to use camelCase by default when sending/receiving requests so you could be introducing more work for yourself (or others using your API) in future.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this. Maybe the code can be written more effectively.

```
[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.HttpGet("map")]
public string GetBeatmap(long id) {
   return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new BeatMap(), Formatting.Indented, new JsonSerializerSettings
      {
         ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
      });
}
```

Comment: thx, but is it not possible to set a global settings in the WebApplication for Json serialization?
I want to keep the class as a return type.

Comment: @ if you make it globally you will have more problem then ever since the most data arrives in a camel case.